# jQuery Portlets saving to Database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have looked extensively on this site & online for an answer to this question. I have tried to apply a number of examples to my problem with no avail.

I have two blocks, named "`Links`" & "`User Links`". Inside each block,they are descriptions (which are blocks themselves) of links on my site which can be individually dragged from left to right.

My problem is I cannot save the data to my database once I press "`Save Changes`", my error is "`Undefined index: quicklink`"

Here is the code.

```
<?php echo Form::open(URL::Base().Route::get('links')->uri(array('action' => 'update')), array('id' => 'links-form', 'class' => 'form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) ?>
<section class="grid_12">
    <div class="block-border">
        <div class="block-content">
            <div class="block-controls">
            <div class="controls-buttons"></div>
            </div>
            <h1>Quick Links</h1>
            <div class="columns">   
                <div class="colx2-left">
                    <fieldset>  
                        <legend>Links</legend>
                            <p class="inline-small-label small-margin">
                                <div class="column">        
                                    <?php if (count($links)): ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($links as $row): ?>      
                                    <div class="portlet">
                                        <div class="portlet-content"><?php echo $row->description ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php endforeach ?>
                                    <?php endif ?>      
                                </div>      
                            </p>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="colx2-right">
                    <fieldset>  
                        <legend>User Links</legend>
                            <p class="inline-small-label small-margin">
                                <div class="column">        
                                    <?php if (count($userlinks)): ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($userlinks as $row): ?>      
                                    <div class="portlet" name="link[]" id="link" multiple="multiple" size="12">
                                        <div class="portlet-content"><?php echo $row->link_id ?></div>
                                    </div>  
                                    <?php endforeach ?>
                                    <?php endif ?>      
                                </div>      
                            </p>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="colx2-left align-center">
                    <?php echo Form::button('save_edit', 'Save Changes', array('id' => 'save_edit', 'type' => 'submit', 'value' => 'save_edit')) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="colx2-right align-center">
                    <?php echo Form::button('cancel_edit', 'Cancel Changes', array('id' => 'cancel_edit', 'type' => 'button', 'value' => 'cancel_edit')) ?>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

```
<?php echo Form::close() ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style>
  body { min-width: 520px; }
  .column { width: 520px; float: left; padding-bottom: 100px; }
  .portlet { margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
  .portlet:hover { cursor: pointer }
  .portlet-header { margin: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 0.2em; }
  .portlet-header .ui-icon { float: right; }
  .portlet-content { padding: 0.4em; }
  .ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; height: 50px !important; }
  .ui-sortable-placeholder * { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column"
    });

    $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
      .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
      .find( ".portlet-content" );

    $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
      $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });

    $( ".column" ).disableSelection();
  });

</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    /**
 * Update the Users settings and details
 *
 * @return void
 */ 
public function action_update()
{
    $this->template = NULL;
    $this->auto_render = FALSE;

    if ($_POST)
    {
        $row = ORM::factory('LinkUser');

        // Remove all current Links
        foreach($row->link->find_all() as $ql)

            $row->remove('link', $ql);

        foreach($_POST['link'] as $ql)
        {
            $row->add('link', $ql);
        }
    }
}
```

MODEL "Link"

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_Link extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'links';

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'qlinkusers' => array(
            'model' => 'LinkUser',
            'foreign_key' => 'link_id',
            'through' => 'links_users',
        ),
    );
}
```

MODEL "LinkUser"

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_LinkUser extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'links_users';

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'link' => array(
            'model' => 'Link',
            'foreign_key' => 'link_id',
            'through' => 'links_users',
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'model' => 'user',
            'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
        ),  
    );
}
```

I am incredibly weak on jQuery, hopefully it is clear what I require......
I want to drag a number of links from the left block to the right block which is so far successful, I cannot save the data to my database once I press "`Save Changes`", my error is "`Undefined index: link`"

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I where you I would use something like the following (totally different then your current script):

When the sorting has changed for your links or whatever you want to log. You can better try it via direct ajax request. What you need to do is determine the action.

In your case it is: "action_update"

You will post the data via ajax by collection the new links/sorting from your html first (or whatever you are trying to save to your DB). Then post it via a URL that you have set in your routing. You link it to your current controller action and you are done:

```
Router::connect('/request/via/ajax/here', array('controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'action_update'));
```

You do not need the predefined Form::button that you are using now. Just log a click event and perform your ajax function.

Remember to use $this->autoRender=false; in your action.

Example for your ajax request:

```
$('.update_button').on('click',function()
{
    $data = $('#links-form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'YourController', 'action'=>'action_update'), true ); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: {data:$data},
        success: function(result,status)
        {
            alert('data saved');
        }
    });
});
```

To check your date first you can log it in your console:

```
console.log($data)
```

Comment: Only got around to seeing this now Rens. I appreciate you taking your time to look at my issue, I will try to apply your advice tomorrow.Cheers.